# How to import XML file data dynamically into SQL Server using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, xml

I have an `.xml` file that contains 30 tables and I want to read all tables and insert the data into a SQL Server database without declaring any variable, means everything is happening dynamically

```
<person>
    <created_by>admin</created_by> 
    <created_on_timestamp>2014-11-19T14:13:54.000Z</created_on_t‌​imestamp> 
    <date_of_birth>1990-04-04</date_of_birth>
    <last_modified_by>admin</last_modified_by> 
    <last_modified_on>2014-11-21T13:29:49.000Z</last_modified_on‌​> 
    <logon_user_id>P10621</logon_user_id> 
    <logon_user_is_active>true</logon_user_is_active> 
    <logon_user_name>P10621</logon_user_name> 
    <person_id>3478</person_id> 
    <person_id_external>P10621</person_id_external> 
    <personal_informatio>
```

---

```
<last_modified_by>admin</last_modified_by> 
<last_modified_on>2014-11-21T14:45:49.000Z</last_modified_on‌​> 
<last_name>Singh</last_name> 
<marital_status>S</marital_status> 
<nationality>IND</nationality> 
<salutation>MR</salutation> 
<start_date>2014-05-01</start_date> 
<personal_information_ind> 
    <country>IND</country> 
    <created_by>admin</created_by> 
    <created_on_timestamp>2014-11-21T13:50:33.000Z</created_on_t‌​imestamp> 
    <custom_string1>hi</custom_string1> 
    <genericNumber1>22</genericNumber1>
```

---

```
<address_information> 
    <address1>-0</address1> 
    <address2>Villa -342,Omax Panorama City</address2> 
    <address3>-0</address3> 
    <address4>manphoollamori@gmail.com</address4> 
    <address5>919828513833</address5> 
    <address_type>home</address_type> 
    <city>Bhiwadi</city> 
    <country>IND</country> 
    <county>India</county> 
    <created_by>admin</created_by> 
    <created_on_timestamp>2014-11-21T15:09:41.000Z</created_on_t‌​imestamp> 
    <end_date>9999-12-31</end_date> 
    <is_global_model_address>false</is_global_model_address> 
    <last_m
```

Comment: Could you add more details, i.e. how the xml file looks like? And share what you have tried.

Comment: Am trying to do first read xml file and insert into dataset then using join combine all tables and then declare fields of xml and database using cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue then insert into database bt when we change xml file then we have to change  all application bt i want to only when xml file is chage my application run fine for all type xml file

Comment: <person>
    <created_by>admin</created_by>
    <created_on_timestamp>2014-11-19T14:13:54.000Z</created_on_timestamp>
    <date_of_birth>1990-04-04</date_of_birth>
    <last_modified_by>admin</last_modified_by>
    <last_modified_on>2014-11-21T13:29:49.000Z</last_modified_on>
    <logon_user_id>P10621</logon_user_id>
    <logon_user_is_active>true</logon_user_is_active>
    <logon_user_name>P10621</logon_user_name>
    <person_id>3478</person_id>
    <person_id_external>P10621</person_id_external>
    <personal_informatio>

Comment: <last_modified_by>admin</last_modified_by>
      <last_modified_on>2014-11-21T14:45:49.000Z</last_modified_on>
      <last_name>Singh</last_name>
      <marital_status>S</marital_status>
      <nationality>IND</nationality>
      <salutation>MR</salutation>
      <start_date>2014-05-01</start_date>
      <personal_information_ind>
        <country>IND</country>
        <created_by>admin</created_by>
        <created_on_timestamp>2014-11-21T13:50:33.000Z</created_on_timestamp>
        <custom_string1>hi</custom_string1>
        <genericNumber1>22</genericNumber1>

Comment: <address_information>
      <address1>-0</address1>
      <address2>Villa -342,Omax Panorama City</address2>
      <address3>-0</address3>
      <address4>manphoollamori@gmail.com</address4>
      <address5>919828513833</address5>
      <address_type>home</address_type>
      <city>Bhiwadi</city>
      <country>IND</country>
      <county>India</county>
      <created_by>admin</created_by>
      <created_on_timestamp>2014-11-21T15:09:41.000Z</created_on_timestamp>
      <end_date>9999-12-31</end_date>
      <is_global_model_address>false</is_global_model_address>
      <last_m

Comment: Please **do not** put code samples or sample data into comments - since you cannot format it, it's **extremely hard** to read it.... Instead: **update** your question by editing it to provide that additional information! Thank you.

Comment: Which I have done for you now, but you definitely need to look it through as there seems to be a lot missing.

Comment: _ bt i want to only when xml file is chage my application run fine for all type xml file_ - do you mean that when xml structure changes your code will need to create new table and columns in database?

Answer (score 0):

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("yourxmlfile.xml");

string databasename = doc.DocumentElement.Name;

foreach (XmlNode node in doc.SelectNodes("/" + databasename + "/*[starts-with(name(), 'SourceTableName')]"))
{
    string tablename = node.Attributes["targetTable"].Value;
    string Columns = "";
    string Values = "";

    foreach (XmlNode field in node.SelectNodes("Field"))
    {
        Columns += (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Columns) ? ", " : "") + field.Attributes["targetField"].Value;
        Values += (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Values) ? ", " : "") + "'" + field.InnerText + "'";
    }

    //Generate insert statement
    string statement = string.Format("Insert Into {0}.{1} ({2}) Values ({3})",
                                    databasename,
                                    tablename,
                                    Columns,
                                    Values);

    Console.WriteLine(statement);
}
```